# How to give space in regex pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate `Adhara number`.

It's working but every digit it needs a space like

```
9999(space)9999(space)9999.
```

I had tried to give `\s` for space but it didn't work.

I had tried this pattern

```
var regaadhar = /^\d{4}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}$/;
```

This is my approach:

```html
var aadhar_number = document.getElementById('aadhar').value;

var regaadhar = /^\d{4}\ \d{4}\ \d{4}\ \d{4}$/g;

if (!regaadhar.test(aadhar.value)) {

    document.getElementById('aadhar').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('aadhar').style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
}
```

Comment: `/(\d{4} \d{4} \d{4})/` ??

Comment: No. Not working

Comment: I don't understand, both your regex and mine work for me. How do you test? `regEx.test(string)` ??

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: My Aadhar number pattern is working but in case of space after every 4 digits. I am asking how to give space after every 4 digits in pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `element` with `id` `aadhar` doesn't exist in question. Then is there a `value` to the `document` or `innerHTML`? I have added both for two different elements.

```js
var aadhar_number = document.getElementById('aadhar').innerHTML;

var regaadhar = /^\d{4}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}$/;

if (!regaadhar.test(aadhar_number)) {

    document.getElementById('aadhar').style.border = "thick solid red";
} else {
    document.getElementById('aadhar').style.border = "thick solid #cccccc";
}

aadhar_number = document.getElementById('aadharIncorrect').value;

if (!regaadhar.test(aadhar_number)) {

    document.getElementById('aadharIncorrect').style.border = "thick solid red";
} else {
    document.getElementById('aadharIncorrect').style.border = "thick solid #cccccc";
}
```

```html
<div id="aadhar">9999 9999 9999</div>
<input id="aadharIncorrect" value="9999 9999 99">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Working code:

```js
var adharNumber = "999999999999";

var newAdhar = adharNumber.replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/,'');

console.log(newAdhar);
```

**Note:** This script works only when the string is numeric not when it is aplhanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/^\d{4}\ \d{4}\ \d{4}\ \d{4}$/g
```

i have just checked and it's working fine.
you can test the same thing here https://regexr.com/